# Can I exclude code from WebApplicationFactory using the ASP.NET Core 6+ WebApplicationBuilder?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory` will bootstrap an ASP.NET Core application in memory for unit tests. It used to do this by discovering and invoking `public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder`.

That `CreateHostBuilder` method was part of an the old pattern from ASP.NET Core 3.x/5, which used a `HostBuilder`. Now we've got `WebApplicationBuilder` instead. And the test `WebApplicationFactory` will call `Program.Main`.

My problem is that `Program.Main` does stuff I don't want done in unit tests.

The thing I don't want in unit tests: it sets up Serilog from `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.json`, and I don't want that in my unit tests, it doesn't make sense. It's not something I can control `WebApplicationFactory` because I do it before I use `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` (which I think that's a sensible decision: after entering `Main` my first priority is to configure logging... just in case).

Is there anyway to convince `WebApplicationFactory` to choose another entry point that allows me to exclude my most basic infrastructural code from the unit test?

Do I have to go back to the old pattern of Program/Startup? Am I doing something misguided and should reconsider my need to exclude code from my tests?

---

In case it matters, here is my `Program` class. Everything in the try would have previously been done via `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run()` and been in `Startup`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConfigureLogging(configuration);

        try
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            _ = builder.Host.UseSerilog();
            _ = builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions ...
            ...

            var app = builder.Build();
            ...

            Dependencies.Register(container, app.Configuration);
            container.Verify();
            
            app.Run();  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private static void ConfigureLogging(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                ...
    }
}
```

And here is my test WebApplicationFactory

```
internal class MyWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string?> _appConfig;
    public IConfiguration? Configuration { get; private set; }

    public MyWebApplicationFactory(SqlSettings sqlSettings)
    {
        _appConfig = new Dictionary<string, string?>
        {
            { "SqlSettings:ConnectionString", sqlSettings.ConnectionString },
        };
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        _ = builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            // Clear config and replace with in memory
            // Won't affect anything that doesn't get config from app, like logging

            config.Sources.Clear();

            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddInMemoryCollection(_appConfig)
                .Build();
            _ = config.AddConfiguration(Configuration);
        });

        _ = builder.UseEnvironment("Test");
    }
}
```

As you can see. I have the opportunity to dump the configuration and add my own for the test. This will flow into my `Dependencies.Register`, but it is too late for logging.

And here's what the old pattern was like. You can see that the basic infrastructural code would not be called by something trying to find `CreateHostBuilder`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConfigureLogging();

        try
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private static void ConfigureLogging()
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            ...

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            ...
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(web =>
        {
            web.UseStartup<Startup>().UseSerilog();
        });
}
```

Comment: I suspect the answer is to use `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` with `ConfigureServices` and `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I see 3 following options:

1. Add some environment variable that will be checked by your `ConfigureLogging` method and disable it.
2. Move away from manually building the configuration to reusing the one provided by the builder itself - `builder.Configuration`:

   ```cs
   var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
   ConfigureLogging(builder.Configuration);
   // ...

   static void ConfigureLogging(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
   {
       Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            ...
   }
   ```

   `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)` throwing should be something very exceptional.
3. The best one in my opinion for this use case - just switch back to the [generic hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and use the previous pattern.

Comment: To add another option use a custom environment (like testing) and switch the logic based on that.